# I'm facing a problem while using "View data layout" in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, helper

Facing problem while using "View data layout" So Please help me. Code are given below. Its showing redline on view data

```
public class Home1Controller : Controller
{

    [ViewData]

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Message = "Hello";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: The ViewDataAttribute class is in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc. It could be that you don't have using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; statement.

Otherwise you can provide more details about the compiler error. "redline" is not enough information since it could be many things. The detailed compiler error would help others help you.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: You need to make sure you are in a .net core project,refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.viewdata?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and check if you miss something.

Comment: Thanks everyone